# QtQuick.Controls 2.0 cannot accept width/height of ApplicationWindow

Tags: qt

**Hi there!**

In any project in the example gallery of Qt oder an example by myself, the import of QtQuick.Controls 2.0 doesn't accept the property width, height or visible in the ApplicationWindow. What's wrong?

I am working with Qt 5.7, Windows 10.

*Thanks for any help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who struggle with the same question, do that: `import QtQuick.Window 2.2`Finally it works!